# Pasting images into Org

Tags: org-mode, clipboard, inline-image, attachment

I'd like to paste images from the system clipboard into an Org file. Emacs should write the clipboard content to a suitable file (likely an attachment) and insert a suitable link (see https://orgmode.org/manual/Images.htm) to it at point.

Has this been implemented yet anywhere?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but this comes close [https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download)

Comment: maybe something like this? https://dev.to/bitschupser/how-to-paste-images-into-emacs-org-mode-running-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2pc0